# Get Woocommerce customer order language

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, qtranslate

I'm developing a complementary plugin for `woocommerce`.
I have a sql request that gets all the order and customer info, but i need to get the language from the order.

How can i detect the language was using a customer when he made an order? Is it registered somewhere?

In other `CMS` like `prestashop` it's stored as `id_lang` in orders and customer tables.

Comment: You will need to save the language as meta for the order. WooCommerce doesn't do this by default because it isn't multilingual by default. So detecting the language used will depend on what plugin you are using to make your site multilingual.

Comment: So let's think about the most used multilingual plugins, i think they are wpml and qtranslate.

Or there is a way I can force woocommerce to store that meta value everytime an user makes an order from my custom plugin?

Comment: You can save any data you'd like as meta data for an order.

Comment: Just to say that WPML already saves a postmeta for orders with user language. the meta it's called "wpml_language"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved, both solutions are OK.

With WPML plugin you can get the value in the table `postmeta` with the `meta_key = wpml_language`

Just added a left join in my SQL query:

```
SELECT O.ID as id_order, O.post_date_gmt as date, M.meta_value as email, M2.meta_value as firstname, M3.meta_value as lastname, M4.meta_value as iso_code
    FROM ".$prefix."posts O 
    LEFT JOIN ".$prefix."postmeta M ON M.post_id = O.ID AND M.meta_key = '_billing_email'
    LEFT JOIN ".$prefix."postmeta M2 ON M2.post_id = O.ID AND M2.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'
    LEFT JOIN ".$prefix."postmeta M3 ON M3.post_id = O.ID AND M3.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'
    LEFT JOIN ".$prefix."postmeta M4 ON M3.post_id = O.ID AND M4.meta_key = 'wpml_language'
    WHERE O.post_type = 'shop_order' AND O.post_status = 'wc-completed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into which plugin you will chose and how it operates, here is how you would save some extra data to the order.

```
// save the extra field when checkout is processed
function kia_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){
    $language = detect_language_with_your_plugin_of_choice() ? detect_language_with_your_plugin_of_choice() : "en";
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_language', $language );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'kia_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
```

And because I had an awful time the one time I tried to use WPML, maybe consider checking out [Multilingual Press](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/).