# Woocommerce: get and print customer language in the order page details

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to create a hook to  get and print the customer language in the admin order page details. I mean the language the customer selected in the site to process his order.

**UPDATE**: I use WPML for languages.

The closest I fount is this post but I can not see how it can help me: [Get Woocommerce customer order language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746821/get-woocommerce-customer-order-language)

I just to print the value somewhere in the **Admin** order page details.

I guess that the code should be something like:

```
function add_language(){  
// get language for the order
// print language in Order Admin page

 }
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'add_language' );
```

Comment: Detecting the language used will depend on what plugin you are using to make your site multilingual, it seems logical that this would be stored in the usermeta table or a custom table provided by the plugin. 
If you can find this information in the usermeta table, 
you can obtain the `$user_id` via the `$order` object and then the meta data via [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)

Comment: Something like this answer, 
but for the language against a member number. [How do i show custom user data on the woocomerce order details page in wp admin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162087/11987538)

Comment: @7uc1f3r I use WPML for languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this because I am not using the plugin but according to the information I have found. The postmeta table contains a meta_key `wpml_language`

```php
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details( $order ) {
    // Get ID
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    
    $wpml_language = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'wpml_language', true );
    
    if ( ! empty ( $wpml_language ) ) {
        echo 'lang = ' . $wpml_language;
    } else {
        echo 'not found!';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: It worked. Can you please tell me how to show it below the Shipping and Billing information? The code show the language above shipping and billing info. Thanks.

Comment: You could use the [`woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L426) or [`woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L513) hook instead